# pass result from subcribe angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created a service that return array of object. How do I pass the result of the service to another function for further processing.

**My subscribe**

```
showFeed(){
  this.service.getCompanies().subscribe((companies) => {
     //console.log(companies);
     console.log(companies.rss.channel.item);
     this.items = companies.rss.channel.item;
  });
}

//How do I pass the result of showFeed() to addItem()
additem(){
    this.hostnamesMap={} // hostname as key, and an array of items as value
    this.items.map((item) => {
        var wordCount = item.link.split("/");
        var result = wordCount[0] + "//" + wordCount[2];
        if(!this.hostnamesMap[result]) { // create an entry of not existing
            this.hostnamesMap[result] = [item];
        } else { // add item to already existing entry
            this.hostnamesMap[result].push(item);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Result is inside, you can access it with right arrow.

Comment: how do you mean "right arrow"

Comment: this._todos._value doest work

Comment: the context doesn't define the subject.

Comment: so, how to do? i'm stucked!!!

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
addItem(){
  var todosss = this._todos.subscribe(val => console.log(val)); 
}
```

note that `todosss` is a `subscription`, you can unsubscribe by calling `todosss.dispose()`

or not use Rx.

```
showFeed() {
  this.service.getCompanies().subscribe((companies) => {
  // ...
  this.items = companies.rss.channel.item;
  this.additem(); // call additem() here
});

additem(){
  this.hostnamesMap={} // hostname as key, and an array of items as value
  this.items.map((item) => {
   var wordCount = item.link.split("/");
   var result = wordCount[0] + "//" + wordCount[2];
   if(!this.hostnamesMap[result]){ // create an entry of not existing
     this.hostnamesMap[result] = [item];
   }else{ // add item to already existing entry
     this.hostnamesMap[result].push(item);
   }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: why use subscribe?

Comment: @netx because this is async stream, you need subscribe to receive something when you push next

Comment: then how do i pass the result without using "next"

Comment: do not use rxjs, just create method with param, then call when you subscribe on service

Comment: can you please direct me on how to do that.. really appreciate

Comment: @netx i mean, i'm updated post above to answer your question with async stream or not.